# How to split a list in n sized chunks, where n is an iterable list of integers?

Tags: python, list, split, chunks

I have a list of words and a list of integers 'n'. How do I split the list of words in 'n' sized chunks (uneven)?

e.g.

```
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'oof', 'banana', 'apple', 'cherries', 'tomato']
n = ['2', '1', '4']
```

output:

```
[['apple', 'orange'], ['oof'], ['banana', 'apple', 'cherries', 'tomato']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer:

```
output = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(n)):
    chunk_size = int(n[i])
    chunk = []
    for j in range(chunk_size):
        index = (i * j) + j
        chunk.append(words[count])
        count = count + 1
    output.append(chunk)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with `iter` and `next`:

```
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'oof', 'banana', 'apple', 'cherries', 'tomato']
n = ['2', '1', '4']
new_words = iter(words)
result = [[next(new_words) for _ in range(int(i))] for i in n]
```

Output:

```
[['apple', 'orange'], ['oof'], ['banana', 'apple', 'cherries', 'tomato']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `O(n)` strategy:

```
words = ['apple', 'orange', 'oof', 'banana', 'apple', 'cherries', 'tomato']
n = ['2', '1', '4']
start = 0
out = []
for num in n:
    num = int(num)
    out.append(words[start:start+num])
    start += num
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to importing numpy or itertools, you can create a new list with the cumulative sum and use that as your index to create your desired output:

```
# itertools.accumulate
from itertools import accumulate
m = [0] + list(accumulate([0] + n))

# numpy.cumsum
import numpy as np
m = np.cumsum([0] + n)

# Create new list
[words[i:j] for i, j in zip(m[:-1], m[1:])]
```